# Urban Airship "error: cannot find symbol method shared()"

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

The "shared()" method is not being recognized for some reason, and this is preventing the code of my App from compiling. The error I see is:

```
error: cannot find symbol method shared()
```

I am using this in my "build.gradle (Module: app)" file:

```
dependencies {
    ......................
    // Urban Airship SDK
    compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.3.+'
    ......................
}
```

I thought this "shared()" method would be included in the Urban Airship SDK version 8.3.+ that I am calling. When I see the Urban Airship Sample app they provide, a "shared()" method is declared at https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/urbanairship-sdk/src/main/java/com/urbanairship/UAirship.java:

```
/**
 * Returns the shared UAirship singleton instance. This method will block
 * until airship is ready.
 *
 * @return The UAirship singleton.
 * @throws IllegalStateException if takeoff is not called prior to this method.
 */
@NonNull
public static UAirship shared() {
    synchronized (airshipLock) {
        if (!isTakingOff && !isFlying) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Take off must be called before shared()");
        }

        return waitForTakeOff(0);
    }
}
```

Any ideas about why the "shared()" method is not available for me? This is an example of how I use it in my code, and I call it several times from different parts of the source code but it is always the same, the method is not recognized:

```
String appid=PushManager.shared().getAPID();
```

Thank you.

Comment: It was working correctly for me before by the way, when I was using "compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-3.3.0.jar')" for the Urban Airship SDK in the dependencies. Now that I am upgrading, I am using this in my dependencies instead: "compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.3.+'". Now the "shared()" method is not working for me. I know they use it in the Urban Airship Sample app, for example at https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/urbanairship-sdk/src/main/java/com/urbanairship/UAirship.java: "UAirship airship = UAirship.shared();".

Comment: I was reading at http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua/#post-api-custom-events this information: "Prior to Android 5.0 SDK: PushManager.shared().setDeviceTagsEnabled(false);. Android SDK 5.0 or later: UAirship.shared().getPushManager() .setDeviceTagsEnabled(false);". I guess the problem is that my code was using Urban Airship SDK 3.3.0 before, and now I am upgrading to 8.3.+, so I need to respect the syntax of the new Urban Airship SDK.

Comment: I also found this information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717398/urbanairship-android-unable-to-getapid: 'APID is no longer used in the 5.x series of Urban Airship. Instead the new "channel" identifier is used. Its essentially the same as the APID.' So instead of "String appid=PushManager.shared().getAPID();" I should probably have "String appid = UAirship.shared().getPushManager().getChannelId();", which does not throw any errors for me and it is also using the "shared()" method I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.3 to 8.3 is pretty big update. We use "channels" now instead of "apids", essentially the same thing but have been updated a bit. We also removed most the singleton accessors for individual modules and moved them to the UAirship instance. New code should be

> UAirship.shared().getPushManager().getChannelId();

I would recommend taking a look at the [Urban Airship Android Guide](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android) as well as the [migration guide](https://docs.urbanairship.com/guides/android-migration/). Other than API changes, we made lots of changes to how to [listening](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android/#android-push-events) and [customizing push notifications](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android/#customizing-push-notifications). Although, customizing notification is not as necessary now that we provide most options through our push API now and airship config.